# Docusign MS Word document changed top margin

Tags: docusignapi

I wrote a C# application to send a MS Word document to signers. I added multiple text tabs, signature tabs, social security tabs, etc. The application reads a local MS Word document, creates the envelope, places the tabs, and sends the document.

Everything was working fine until today when all the tabs are misplaced in the document sent by DocuSign. When reviewing the original document and the final document sent by DocuSign, I noticed that the top spaces/margins of the pages aren't being respected by DocuSign which causes all the fields to be misplaced. There were no changes to the original document. Does anyone have any idea of what could be the issue?

Comment: how are you placing the tabs? using anchor string or X/Y position?

Comment: You seem to say that everything was working fine until today and that "There were no changes to the original document". Well, be aware that DocuSign has offset for different fields that are undocumented. That might be the case ? But providing a piece of your code might help to troubleshoot your issue

Comment: I am placing the tabs with X/Y position. See the screenshot below. I put both documents side by side. The document on the left is correct and respects the original word document used. The document on the right is what started happening without changes to the document nor the code. The top margin is being changed when the document is sent. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yzBZk8oJ9KZ2SgaATg2dWL_iJcUrPbcd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. I reset the top margins on all pages and the problem is gone. Basically, I changed the margins and put them back to where I needed them.